# How to align HTML horizontaly using CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

if possible, is it possible to align HTML elements horizontaly in one line 
 such as for example with my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Invoice</Title>
        <body>
            <header>
            <h1>Cafe au Lait Invoice</h1>
            <h2><?php echo $address;  ?></h2>
            <h3>Ph: <?php echo $phone_no;?></h3>
            <h4>Date: <?php echo "$date at $time";?>
            </header>
        Coffee Ordered: 
            <?php 
                if ($cappuccino > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>Cappuccino ";
                }
                if ($espresso > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>Espresso ";
                }
                if ($double > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>Double Espresso";
                }
                if ($latte > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>Latte ";
                }
                if ($flat > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>Flat White";
                }
                if ($ice > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>Ice Coffee";
                }
            ?>  
            Qty: 
            <?php 
                if ($cappuccino > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>$cappuccino_qty ";
                }
                if ($espresso > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>$espresso_qty ";
                }
                if ($double > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>$double_espresso_qty";
                }
                if ($latte > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>$latte_qty ";
                }
                if ($flat > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>$flat_white_qty";
                }
                if ($ice > 0)
                {
                    Print "<p>$ice_coffee_qty";
                }
            ?>  

        </body> 
    </head>
</Html>
```

That "Coffee Ordered" and "Qty" next to each other.  Do I have to rewrite the code in order to do so? My idea is something like this template,http://www.docstoc.com/docs/46248123/Pizza-Hut-Price-List ,where "Pizza Hutt..." is "Coffee Ordered" and "Item" is "Qty".

Comment: You don't have any clue what the code above does, do you?

Comment: Surely not. I would also expect `if ($cappuccino_qty > 0)`

Comment: sorry i was in a rush

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a table in html with invisible borders. You can do it like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then make the border invisible trough css like this:

```
table, tr, td {
    border: none;
}
```

Take a read here about tables:
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html

And here about table styling:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html

Comment: quick question how do I make it invisible?

Comment: I found that you could just use <table border = "0"> to get invisible borders